# Rename a file with a new filename saved in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, file, rename

I need to rename any file with the name already exists in the folder. After it is renamed that I can move it.

```
 if [ -e $BACKUP$PARAM1 ]; then
   echo -e "In this directory there is already a file with the same name. \n"
   read -p "Please, write a new filename: " newname
   mv "$PARAM1" "$newname"
   mv $PARAM1 $BACKUP
   fi
```

The first mv command doesn't work. Any idea to solve it?

I write a dirty simulation:

in `$BACKUP$PARAM1` there is the full folder of a file moved to Backup directory. `$BACKUP` contains "Backup/", `$PARAM1` contains "song.mp3", so `$BACKUP$PARAM1` = Backup/song.mp3.

If in Backup folder already exists a file called "song.mp3", I'll rename my file before to move in Backup.
So I write a new filename: "music.mp3", stored in `$newname` then proceed to the change of name using the mv command: `mv "$PARAM1" "$newname"`---> "song.mp3" to "music.mp3".

At the and, I move the renamed file to the "Backup" folder: `mv $PARAM1 $BACKUP` to obtain: "Backup/music.mp3".

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ -e "$BACKUP$PARAM1" ]; then
   echo -e "In this directory there is already a file with the same name. \n"
   read -p "Please, write a new filename: " newname
   mv "$BACKUP$PARAM1" "$BACKUP$newname"
   fi
```

You can rename your file and at the same time move it to backup as above. Also use absolute pathnames for example instead of "$PARAM1" use "$BACKUP$PARAM1".

Also check to see if your path name for  your backdirectory is correct for example instead of "Backup/" it could be "/Backup/" if the backup directory is in another directory